# How can I animate an element after page is fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

```
(function() {
    $('body').css('visibility', 'visible');
})();
```

This is the code I tried using to make that happen. However, it's not working properly. So, please help.

Comment: There is nothing waiting for the DOM to be loaded. Did you mean `$(function(){`…`});`?

Comment: use load function

Comment: Instead of leaving a thanking comment, use the "accept answer" button, if you've gotten an answer that helped with your problem, so others know the question has already been resolved without reading the entire thread. This also rewards the helper with points.

Answer (score 0):

You can use load function

```
$(window).load(function(){ 
   $('body').css('visibility', 'visible'); 
});
```

You need to specify in css like this, so that this will execute first and later load will execute by overriding this

```
body{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much bro...:)) I'm new to java script, thanks for the help :)